# Android MediaPlayer error (1, -2147483648) on android 4.1

Tags: android, video-streaming, media-player, android-mediaplayer

I have an error when i try to reproduce a video don't work. My code is in the link http://pastebin.com/94eYm4NK.
This error happen only in specific cellphones.

Comment: I guess there is problem with your code, Generally when this error occurs it means that the video format you are playing is not supported by your device. Also If you are trying this code in emulator then I suggest you to check this code on real device first.

Comment: I test my code in different devices, the error only happen in motorola razr. i don't know why.

Comment: that means motorola razr is not supporting that video formate. There is nothing wrong with your code.

Comment: The problem was the format of the video, Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem and this fixed the issue:

```
videoUrl= videoUrl.replaceFirst("https", "http");
```

Comment: I also try but i solved my issue. The problem was the format of the video.